# How to pass a function with a parameter to an inner component in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

I have a child component that requires data from a parent component in order to call its function. How do I put this in code?

**parent.html**

```
<child-component>getDailyForeCast(element.symbol)</child-component>
```

**child.html**

```
<canvas id="canvas"> {{ getDailyForeCast(symbol) }}</canvas>
```

**ChildComponent**

```
getDailyForeCast(symbol){

...}
```

Comment: Is your function defined in your parent component?

Comment: It's defined in the child component as seen in the code snippet

Comment: Your question is not making sense to me. Do you want to pass symbol from parent to child?

Comment: yes, that's the idea

Comment: I have answered the solution.  Is your problem resolved using the below solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not need to pass the function to the child component.
You only want to pass your **element.symbol** to the child component, you can do this using @Input in your child.

```
<child-component [symbol]="element.symbol"> </child-component>
```

In your child component you can define the variable in .ts file:

```
@Input('symbol') symbol;
```

and simply use this symbol in your html file using **{{symbol}}**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Input` decorator to bind a property from another component. Docs: https://angular.io/api/core/Input

Now you can use the symbol in your child component and do whatever with it.

**parent.component.html**

```
<child-component [symbol]='element.symbol'></child-component>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input() symbol;

getDailyForeCast(){
  // use this.symbol and return some output    
...}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<canvas id="canvas"> {{ getDailyForeCast() }}</canvas>
```

*PS: If multiple components are involved, you may consider using a service.*

Comment: Whatever you have written in the answer is conveying the same solution compared to my answer above. So I think this answer is not contributing more towards it.

Comment: @Minal Shah They were written around the same time as I recall. There are some extra details in here however, the Input documentation reference, how to access an input, an example of the child template and the suggestion of using a service instead.